# Multiselect em formato dropdown no Bootstrap 4

Tags: dropdown, bootstrap-4, jquery-ui-multiselect

Estou com dificuldades de encontrar um multiselect no bootstrap 4 com formato "dropdown". O único elemento que ele permite é deste modo:

[image: única opção de multiselect no bootstrap 4]

Gostaria de deixá-lo neste formato:

[image: Formato Desejado]

Pelo o que me lembre, isto não acontecia na versão anterior do bootstrap.

Código utilizado:

```
<link href="styles\bootstrap-4.1.1\bootstrap-4.1.1\dist\css\bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<select multiple class="form-control" data-actions-box="true">
           <option>Mustard</option>
           <option>Ketchup</option>
           <option>Relish</option>
</select>
```

Alguém consegue me ajudar?

Comment: Essa demo funciona perfeitamente, porém só o bootstrap não é suficiente precisa instalar o multiselect.

https://www.codeply.com/go/Z8XiNJAkjc/bootstrap-4-multiselect

Comment: https://select2.org/ veja já exite para BS4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tente:

```
<select class="selectpicker" multiple>
  <option>Mustard</option>
  <option>Ketchup</option>
  <option>Relish</option>
</select>
```

Fonte: https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/examples/